# How do I use a value in a loop outside of the loop?

Tags: audio, loops, for-loop

I asked another question that wasnt answered, which led me to this question. I have a for loop that makes an array of the samples in a sound file. I do it to two files, and try to combine them in a third file. However, the array of values only exists within the for loop so I can't use the values I need in the third because to I need to access the array of samples in the third file using a for loop as well. A nested for loop doesnt seem to make sense in this situation.

Sorry forgot to mention I'm using python.
This is the chunk of the code that confuses me.

```
for index in getSamples(sound1):
    v1 = getSampleValue(index)

  for index in getSamples(sound2):
    v2 = getSampleValue(index)

  for index in getSamples(sound3):
    setSampleValue(index, v1+v2)
```

So the code basically gets all the samples from sound1, all the samples from sound 2, and tries to set the samples in sound3(same length as both sounds) to the combination of each sample at each index.

However when this only plays/explores a blank sound for sound 3. I think the problem is that v1 and v2 are only equal to the values of the entire array within the individual for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you intend to do since you don't provide any chunks of code.
But basically, yes you can. I'll write something in php:

```
$myarray = array(); //init the array
for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){
   //do something with myarray
}
//you can use myarray here
```

The point is : declare the "whatever you want to use" outside the loop before the loop started

Answer (score 0):

in order to use a variable outside of the loop to reference the array, you need to initialize that variable outside of the loops.  This gives you a reference to the array.

```
var array = new Array();

for (int x=0; x<sample.length(); x++) {
    //do stuff in the loop to 'array' variable
}

//do what you want with 'array' after the loop
```